# Cocoa (Xcode 4), Changing Label on one NIB from another NIB

Tags: xcode, cocoa, xcode4, nib

Simple task: 
I have an application with 2 NIB files (each NIB file has its own controller).
I already suceeded in displaying the window of the 2nd NIB file like I wanted to, but now, I want to click a button on NIB 2 and change a Label on NIB 1.

Now the connecting of the outlets on the NIBs has been done, the problem seems to be to tell Controller2 to change the label in Controller1.

I cant seem to get it done. Is there not some simple call like

```
[Controller1 [Label setStringValue: @"Hi"]];
```

(I also tried to create a method to change the Label in Controller1, then instantiate an object of Controller1 in Controller2 and call my newly created ChangeLabel method. This doesnt produce an error, but it doesnt give me the result either).

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that what you want is to use delegation.

You should declare a delegate method to be implemented in **Controller1** that takes a parameter of type **NSString** (your label) that is set in **Controller2**.